# How come node.js doesn't catch my errors?

Tags: javascript, debugging, exception, node.js, error-handling

```
var api_friends_helper = require('./helper.js');
try{
    api_friends_helper.do_stuff(function(result){
        console.log('success');
    };
}catch(err){
    console.log('caught error'); //this doesn't hit!
}
```

And inside `do_stuff`, I have:

```
function do_stuff(){
    //If I put the throw here, it will catch it! 
    insert_data('abc',function(){
        throw new Error('haha');
    });
}
```

How come it never logs 'caught error'? Instead, it prints the stack-trace and the error object to screen:

```
{ stack: [Getter/Setter],
  arguments: undefined,
  type: undefined,
  message: 'haha' }
Error: haha
    at /home/abc/kj/src/api/friends/helper.js:18:23
    at /home/abc/kj/src/api/friends/db.js:44:13
    at Query.<anonymous> (/home/abc/kj/src/node_modules/mysql/lib/client.js:108:11)
    at Query.emit (events.js:61:17)
    at Query._handlePacket (/home/abc/kj/src/node_modules/mysql/lib/query.js:51:14)
    at Client._handlePacket (/home/abc/kj/src/node_modules/mysql/lib/client.js:312:14)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (native)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:64:17)
    at /home/abc/kj/src/node_modules/mysql/lib/parser.js:71:14
    at Parser.write (/home/abc/kj/src/node_modules/mysql/lib/parser.js:576:7)
```

Notice that if I put the throw RIGHT AFTER the do_stuff(), then it will catch it.

How can I make it catch, even if I put it nested inside another function?

Comment: What is `insert_data('abc'){ throw new Error('haha') }` supposed to be? That isn't valid syntax. What does your code really look like?

Comment: @TIMEX you can't catch errors of asynchronous environements, it doesnt work that way. Stop using `try catch`

Comment: @Raynos how do I catch errors in Node.js then?

Comment: @TIMEX use the `err` parameter on callbacks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one of the downsides of using NodeJS. It basically has two methods on which errors are handled; One through using the try/catch blocks, and other by passing the first argument of every callback function as an error.

The problem is because of the event-loop asynchronous model. You can use the '[uncaughtException](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.3/api/process.html#event_uncaughtException_)' event to catch errors that were not caught, but it has a become an usual program paradigm in Node.JS to use the first argument of the callback function to show if there any errors, as such: (I never used MySQL with NodeJS before, just making a general example)

```
function getUser( username, callback ){
    mysql.select("SELECT username from ...", function(err,result){
        if( err != null ){
            callback( err );
            return;
        }

        callback( null, result[0]);
    });
}    

getUser("MyUser", function(err, user){
    if( err != null )
        console.log("Got error! ", err );
    else
        console.log("Got user!");
});
```

Comment: It's not one of the downsides of using node.js. It's one of the advantages, you get to kill try catch and use `(err, data)` callbacks

Comment: @Raynos I don't understand why that's a good thing? try catch is a consise idiom for handling unforeseen circumstances... having a parameter that is going to be null most of the time seems convoluted and like a design smell!

Comment: @DanielUpton try catch is ugly, it's slow as hell, doesn't work asynchronously and crashes your application completely

Comment: @Raynos try catch doesnt crash your application. The purpose of it is not to crash your application. "slow as hell", i dont know about this.

Comment: Bottom line; try-catch in an async model isn't a reliable pattern. However, .catch( function(err){...} ); SHOULD work as a promise design pattern, but alas... seems rather arbitrary :\

Comment: Everyone here is way off the mark.

Do some reading on promises/async/await — this is the way of the future.

And yes, async/await allows try/catch blocks to work on async code now, which is quite elegant