# Why does NodeJS fail to catch this exception?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have this TypeScript code (edited for the most relevant parts):

```js
try {
  await this.downloadSourcePicStreamToS3('url', 'filename');
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
  return;
}
```

And downloadSourcePicStreamToS3 is this:

```js
private downloadSourcePicStreamToS3(url: string, filename: string): Promise<void> {
  const bytecount = () => {
    let size = 0;
    const passThrough = new stream.PassThrough();
    passThrough.on('data', chunk => {
      size += Buffer.byteLength(chunk);
      if (size > 60_000_000) {
        throw 'TOO_BIG';
      }
    });
    return passThrough;
  };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    stream.pipeline(
      got.stream(url, {...}),
      bytecount(),
      this.s3.uploadSourcePicStream(filename),
      err => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve();
        }
      }
    );
  });
}
```

Basically, it's just checking if a file downloaded as a stream is too big, and throwing an error if it is.

But somehow, when I run this on a file that's too big, I get `ERROR Uncaught Exception "TOO_BIG"`.

I tried by throwing a proper exception (`throw new Error('too big')`), same thing (except obviously with an Error object). I also tried "promisifying" the pipeline (`pipeline = util.promisify(stream.pipeline);`), same again.

The only similar question I found was [How come node.js doesn't catch my errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276132/how-come-node-js-doesnt-catch-my-errors/8276288), but it's quite old and not really solved. I don't want to use the `uncaughtException` event, since there's no reason this exception wouldn't be caught in the first place... Any idea how I can make it catch successfully?

Comment: two things I am curious about:
- replace `if (err) {` with `if (true)` and see if that gets caught
- put a console.log before the reject line to see if the original error ever gets rejected

I wonder if the problem is the reject never getting caught, or stream.pipeline never calling the error callback when the error you are looking at happens

Comment: @Alex028502 for some reason, unlike what the Node documentation says (https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_streams_callback), the pipeline calls the callback before it is complete... So when my bytecount function throws an error, execution is already passed the try catch block. Asynchronous by default is really the hellish point of JS :x

Comment: JS is actually synchronous by default :)

Comment: What's `got.stream(url, {...})`?

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky it's this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/got#streams